# Add data to JSON child array

Tags: php, json

This is my JSON file(database.json):

```
{
  "doctors": [
    {
      "ID": "ahmadakhavan",
      "pass": "1234",
      "name": "Ahmad Akhavan",
      "profilePic": "address",
    },
    {
      "ID": "akramparand",
      "pass": "1234",
      "name": "Akram Parand",
      "profilePic": "address",
    }
  ],
  "games": [
    {
      "ID": "shuttlefuel_1",
      "locked": "0",
      "logo": "gameLogo",
    },
    {
      "ID": "birthdaycake",
      "locked": "0",
      "logo": "gameLogo",
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "ID": "alirezapir",
      "prescribes": [
        {
          "doctorName": "doctor1",
          "done": "yes",
          "gameId": "wordschain"
        },
        {
          "doctorName": "doctor2",
          "done": "no",
          "gameId": "numberlab"
        }
      ],
      "profilePic": "address"
    },
    {
      "ID": "amirdibaei",
      "pass": "1234",
      "profilePic": "address"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add a child under `prescribes` array for a specific ID.

**Below is what I have done in my PHP code to do this:**

```
 <?php 
  $username = $_REQUEST['name'];
  $data = $_REQUEST['data'];

  //Load the file
 $contents = file_get_contents('./database.json');
  $arraydata = json_decode($data,true);
 //Decode the JSON data into a PHP array.
 $contentsDecoded = json_decode($contents, true );
     foreach($contentsDecoded['users'] as $item){
         if($item['ID'] == $username){
             if(!isset($item['prescribes'])){
                 $item['prescribes'] = Array();
             }
             array_push($item['prescribes'],$arraydata);
            $json = json_encode($contentsDecoded, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
            file_put_contents('./database.json', $json);  
             exit('1');
             exit;
         }
     }
    exit('0'); 
    exit;
 ?>
```

If I echo `$item['prescribes']` after the line `array_push($item['prescribes'],$arraydata);` I see data added to it, but the original file (`database.json`) won't show new added data.

(meaning that this new data is not added to `$contentsDecoded`)

Comment: what a "database":)) its a file man a json file :)))

Comment: @madalinivascu Ok :)) its just a tiny JSON file...

Comment: why aren't you doing `if(!isset($item['prescribes'])){
                 $item['prescribes'] =[$arraydata];
             }` ?

Comment: @madalinivascu because i'm ADDING new item to `prescribes` array, i don't want to completely replace it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `foreach()` code like below:-

```
foreach($contentsDecoded['users'] as &$item){ //& used as call by reference
    if($item['ID'] == $username){
        $item['prescribes'][] = $arraydata; //assign new value directly
        $json = json_encode($contentsDecoded, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
        file_put_contents('./database.json', $json);  
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your foreach to change the $contentsDecoded array:

```
foreach($contentsDecoded['users'] as $key => $item){
         if($item['ID'] == $username){
             if(!isset($item['prescribes'])){
                 $contentsDecoded['users'][$key]['prescribes'] = Array();
             }
             array_push($contentsDecoded['users'][$key]['prescribes'],$arraydata);
            $json = json_encode($contentsDecoded, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
            file_put_contents('./database.json', $json);  
             exit('1');
             exit;
         }
     }
```